# JMS Reliability, handling Server down

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, reliability

I am trying to create a reliable JMS environment using ActiveMQ. I am planning to go for a JDBC master slave clustering approach in which I can persist the messages received by master server to database and slave server can pick those messages and run them in case the master server dies. But I don't have a solution to the situation in which both the master and slave go down(due to any reason). If that happens, will the messages sent by producer get lost for ever? I can do something like persisting messages to database and executing them after one of the JMS servers recover, but is there a better/built-in solution to handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

> I can do something like persisting messages to database and executing
>   them after one of the JMS servers recover, but is there a
>   better/built-in solution to handle such scenarios?

You've got the right idea. If the producer can't connect, under normal circumstances, it will throw an exception. You want a store-and-forward (SAF) producer; if the client can't reach the destination, messages are stored locally on the client file system, and sent when the client reconnects with the broker.

Based on nos' comments below, it appears ActiveMq supports [store-and-forward](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) using local storage for clients I've asked nos to submit his comments as the answer.

Comment: Note that with activemq you can also embed a broker in the client application and have it forward to the "real" broker, essentially giving you SAF on the client.

Comment: @nos Interesting, did not know that! Is the embeddable broker the same heavyweight process as a server-side broker? If broker embedding is a resource hog on the client, it's counter productive; if not, that's the solution, 100%.

Comment: It's the same code, though you normally don't activate all the features/modules. It's not heavy weight, embedding activemq is even often used for just inter-thread communication (with the vm:// transport)

Comment: So it's a concurrency framework as well? Very cool! I learned something today! I was about to update my answer, but out of respect, I'll remove it if you want to post your answer instead, ;-) Let me know

Comment: Its really cool that activemq has a feature like that, but it still does not resolve my issue of handling the situation when all the JMS servers fail. Am I being over cautious? If not, is "persisting to database" the safest option I have? I am trying to be more dependant on database because my whole application will crash incase of database failure, so there is no chance of missed messages. Please acknowledge..

Comment: Brokers may be configured to persist messages to a database, and that works for brokers on server and those embedded in clients. Beyond that, I'm not sure what is your concern. There's always edge cases in JMS where messages _may_ get dropped, and some providers are better than others in avoiding such cases, commercial products being the best, of course.